# How can I use a client component in nextJS 13, that renders on every page without unmounting when I use app directory?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, components, next.js13

I want an interactive component render on each page of my app, and keep it open when navigating between pages

The GlobalPlayer is the component I want to render on each page without unmounting

```
export const Providers = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={themeMode}>
      <PlayerProvider>
        <GlobalPlayer />
        <GlobalStyle />
        <HeroSection theme={theme} toggleTheme={handleToggleTheme} />
        {children}
      </PlayerProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};


//RootLayout
<html lang="en" className={radioFonts.className}>
      <body>
        <StyledComponentsRegistry>
          <Providers>{children}</Providers>
        </StyledComponentsRegistry>
      </body>
    </html>
```